# SharePoint Search Managed property for page comments count

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am using PnP Modern Search Webparts(V4) on SharePoint site. There I have used PnP Modern Search Result webpart. I want to use comment count to sort the results.

In SharePoint Online tenant level Search settings, I have mapped crawl property **ows_CommentCount**  to predefined managed property called **RefinableInt31**. I waited for one day to finish the crawl but I didn't get any value in **RefinableInt31** managed property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ows_CommentCount is already mapped to the out-of-the-box managed property CommentCount. I would recommend using this managed property or ensuring that the managed property you want to use is configured using similar settings to the CommentCount managed property.

Comment: I can see out-of-the-box managed property CommentCount property is there but it's not mapped to any crawl property plus it's type of text so can't use it for sorting.

Comment: Is there any comments in your site? Maybe it hasn't been initialised yet.

Comment: There are many pages and documents where comments are present

Comment: you may need to contact Microsoft support because CommentCount has ows_CommentCount mapped in my tenant